# Add event Calendar app URL Scheme in iOS

Tags: objective-c, calendar, add-in

I am trying to navigate from my app to calendar app.So is there any specific scheme for navigating from the app to calendar app add Event option.I have researched in finding the url schemes but I didn't got any for calendar.
Please can anyone tell me what are the url schemes for calendar app.
Thank You.

Comment: I am using [UIApplication sharedApplication] openurl:[NSUrl UrlWithString:@"calshow://"] to navigate to calendar but it takes me to main view.Instead i want to navigate to add event button in calendar